# Parsing a lot of dynamic data from json file

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm fairly new to C# and a lot of the libraries, but I'm trying to deserialize a json file that has a bunch of non-dynamic fields followed by a bunch of dynamically named structures with more dynamically sized/named structures underneath them.

Example of json:

```
"Header": {
  "date": "Aug 30 2020",
  "time": "14:00:00"
},
...
Other fields that will remain static
...
// Start of fields that can grow/shrink and be added to/deleted from
"Birthday": {
  "MessageIndex": 0,
  "Info Array Size": 3,
  "Info": {
    "Date": 30,
    "Month": 8,
    "Year": 2020
  },
},
"Time of Day": {
  "MessageIndex": 1,
  "Info Array Size": 3,
  "Info": {
    "Hour": 2,
    "Minute": 0,
    "Second": 0
  },
},
"Height": {
  "MessageIndex": 2,
  "Info Array Size": 2,
  "Info": {
    "Feet": 6,
    "Inches": 2
  },
},
// Continues on for any number of messages
```

I'm looking to create a tool to be able to parse and document what is in this information without having to add a JsonConverter for each new thing that gets added.  Instead I'm looking for something that can
parse any number of items (like "Birthday", "Time of Day", "Height") that have an unknown name and a field named "Info" underneath it with an unknown number of fields and each of those fields name is unknown at the time of running the tool.

I was looking to use JSON.net (or any other available library really), but if that doesn't work I'm fine parsing the file manually.  I'd just rather avoid that if possible.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you make the items an array and give the message a name...thats what json arrays are for...the index field you have is screaming that you should have an array

Comment: Technically the field values were just filled with fake data that I quickly came up with, but I think either way you are correct that this would be better as an array.  There are other things relying on the JSON file to be exactly the way it is currently, but that can be pushed back on.

Hypothetically if I could go that route, would the same issue arise with what is stored in the "Info" structures now?  Would there be an easy way to access the fields inside those structures without knowing essentially anything about those fields?

Comment: that too would be an array of key/value pairs